# Open the same file multiple times

Tags: sublimetext

I want to view the same file side-by-side. How do I open up two (or more) tabs for a single file?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

File | New View into File will open a second tab for the same file. This can be moved into another window or tab group.

Comment: If you want an equivalent keyboard shortcut, use the Command Palette: `Ctrl+Shift+P`, type "file view", hit `Enter`

Comment: Or alternatively `Alt+F, E`.

Answer (score 34):

- Go into the pane you want to see the file in.
- Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> (Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd>) to get the list of files available.
- Select the one you're after and it will be loaded into the current pane

(Even if it's already open in another pane.)

Answer (score 16):

1. go to `view > layout > Columns:2`
2. go to `File > New View Into File`
3. then drag new Tab into new Column

Comment: Thanks, the missing instructions for the others replies was the layout one

Answer (score 2):

Multiple tabs or Columns? The first is with File -> New File , the second with View -> Layout -> Columns.

Answer (score 1):

For side by side view in mac:

`⌥ + ⌘ + 2` to split window (another group)

select the tab you want to move to another group (group 2)

`⌃ + ⇧ + 2` move selected tab to group 2

like this you can split you window in to 4 columns, 2 rows and a grid

Comment: This answers a different question; the issue is getting the same file into two of those panes.

Comment: I think what i've explains does the same thing for which this question has been asked. Just try out

Comment: For me it moves the current file into the new tab, it doesn't duplicate the file in the new tab. That's different than what's being asked; compare your answer to the accepted one. I didn't downvote, but I'm pretty sure this doesn't open the same file in two panes.

Comment: This works and answers the question, but you do need to have your target file opened twice. That can be accomplished with `File > New View` starting from the file you want split. Then you'll have the file in a 2nd tab to follow step two above.

Answer (score 0):

Click File then click Split view